# Teamcity buildagent on mac, environment variable not visible to Teamcity?

Tags: mac-osx, teamcity

Having problems setting up a Mac as a buildagent for TeamCity. It works for basic builds, but I'm unable to meet build requirements for our main build.

Unmet requirements shown in Teamcity:
env.NGINX_EXE exists
(a few others too, but I'm gonna handle those when I get this one working)

I've installed NGINX, and it's running. The problem is that the environment variable I've created, doesn't register with TeamCity. What I did was add the following line to /etc/profile: 
export NGINX_EXE=/usr/local/bin/nginx 
 
- and restarted (several times).

Typing env in a terminal window lists the system variables as far as I know, and that list shows among other things: 
 
NGINX_EXE=/usr/local/bin/nginx 

I would have thought this was what was needed by TeamCity, but it still shows the requirement as unmet.

I don't really know Macs, I work with windows (and to a lesser degree - linux), so if you have any tips for me, bear that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file `buildAgent/launcher/conf/wrapper.conf` which passes variables to the `JVM` which the `teamcity` agent runs under.

Search for `wrapper.conf` on the teamcity site. For example [this page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents)